# Is it possible to use variable names dynamically in SASS each loop?

Tags: variables, sass, each

This is a simplified example. What I'd like to do is use the items in the array to output variable values I've previously created. The syntax below that tries create a variable by concatenating a '$' is obviously wrong but I'm using it to make it clear what I'm trying to do.

```
$puma-width: 100px;
$slug-width: 200px;

@each $animal in puma, slug {
  .#{$animal}-title {
    width: $+#{$animal}-width;
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
.puma-title {
   width: 100px;
}
.slug-title {
   width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's something that I wanted in SASS as well, but after reading their discussion list, I concluded that this kind of variable interpolation is not supported yet.

I didn't try Less, but their [documentation](http://lesscss.org/#-variables) suggests it would be possible with @@ syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to pass a map instead of item list for the @each directive. The following will work:

```
@each $animal, $width in (puma, 100px),
                         (slug, 200px) {
  .#{$animal}-title {
    width: #{$width};
  }
}
```